# exception: bad_weak_ptr while shared_from_this

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I get exception: std::bad_weak_ptr when I do this->shared_from_this()

```
template<typename TChar>
class painter_record_t
{
.......
private:
    std::shared_ptr<i_painter_t> _owner;
}
```

Here I want to set the "problem" object in constructor:

```
template<typename TChar>
class stream_record_t : public painter_record_t<TChar>
{
public:
    stream_record_t(std::shared_ptr<i_painter_t> owner) : painter_record_t(owner)
    {
    //...
    }
}
```

I have the base class:

```
class i_painter_t
{
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<painter_record_t<char>> get_entry() = 0;
}
```

And derived class, in which I want to send the smart pointer to the base abstract class, but get an exception:

```
class painter_t : public i_painter_t, public std::enable_shared_from_this<painter_t>
{
public:         

    std::unique_ptr<painter_record_t<char>> get_entry()
    {               
        return std::unique_ptr<painter_record_t<char>>(new stream_record_t<char>(static_cast< std::shared_ptr<i_painter_t> >(this->shared_from_this())));
    }
}
```

I also try this, but have the same problem:

```
class painter_t : public i_painter_t, public std::enable_shared_from_this<painter_t>
{
public:         

    std::unique_ptr<painter_record_t<char>> get_entry()
    {               
        return std::unique_ptr<painter_record_t<char>>(new stream_record_t<char>(this->shared_from_this()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for [`enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) to work, you need to store pointer to `this` in `std::shared_ptr` prior to calling `shared_from_this()`.

> Note that prior to calling shared_from_this on an object t, there must be a std::shared_ptr that owns t.

You may want to make `painter_t` constructor private and expose a factory method to ensure that every `painter_t`created  is managed by `shared_ptr`:

```
class painter_t : public i_painter_t, public std::enable_shared_from_this<painter_t>
{
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<painter_t> create() { return std::make_shared<painter_t>(); }
}
```

Comment: The factory method `create()` will not work because `std::make_shared()` doesn't have access to the private constructor of `painter_t`. Instead the body of `create()` should be `return std::shared_ptr<painter_t>(new painter_t());`

Comment: You can make a private constructor available to `std::make_shared` by wrapping it into an inner struct. To the private section of `painter_t` add `struct MakeConstructorPublic;` and define it:
```struct painter_t::MakeConstructorPublic : public painter_t {
    template <typename... Args>
    MakeConstructorPublic(Args&& ...args)
        : painter_t(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}
};
```
Then you can use `std::make_shared<MakeConstructorPublic>` in the factory method.
See here: [http://cpp.sh/65qbr](http://cpp.sh/65qbr)